# How can JasperReports export a range of pages to a text file?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I need to print reports on a matrix printer in text mode.

I found an example of how to export the entire report to a text file using JRTextExporter, but did not find how to export a range of pages.

```
JRTextExporter exporter = new JRTextExporter();

exporter.setParameter(JRTextExporterParameter.PAGE_WIDTH, 80);
exporter.setParameter(JRTextExporterParameter.PAGE_HEIGHT, 40);
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, outputFileName);
exporter.exportReport();
```

Suppose I have a report on 100 pages, I need to export / print  on a matrix printer in text mode from page 15 to page 32.

Comment: Sorry for my English